# Optimistic locking in JPA how does it work?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I understand what is optimistic locking and "how it work" but I don't know how can I implement it on Java EE.

I have an entity in JPA and I add one more *version* column and I annotated it with `@Version` . But to have an optimistic locking management I need only @Version annotation?

This is my Java Class:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    //other variables
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;
 //other code
}
```

In my project I use **Stateless session bean** to access to Entity class and persist more operations, so I use  `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)` by default to handle my transaction.

My doubt is: 
with `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)` (    independently what is `@TransactionAttribute` (REQUIRED,MANDATORY etc)) and only annotating `version` variable in MyClass.java I obtain the optimistic locking management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [*Pro JPA 2: Mastering the Java™ Persistence API*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219564):

> A couple of words of warning about version fields are in order. The first is that **they are not guaranteed to be updated**, either in the managed entities or the database, **as part of a bulk update operation**. (...) The second point worth remembering is that version fields will be **automatically updated only when either the non-relationship fields or the owning foreign key relationship fields** (e.g., many-to-one and one-to-one source foreign key relationships) **are modified**. (...) By default, **JPA assumes (...) Read Committed** isolation. Normal execution using version locking works with Read Committed isolation to provide additional data-consistency checks in the face of interleaved writes. Satisfying **tighter locking constraints** than what this locking offers **requires that an additional locking strategy be used**.

(emphasis mine)

So, to answer your question: **No. Using `@Version` does not cover all the bases.**

The aforementioned additional locking strategy involves passing an appropriate locking mode (`OPTIMISTIC` or `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`) to `EntityManager.lock()`, `EntityManager.refresh()`, `EntityManager.find()`, and `Query.setLockMode()`, where applicable. I won't go into more details here and instead recommend a [follow up read](http://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking) (there's a detailed discussion in the book as well).