# Spring JPA. The right way to update database values

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-data-jpa, isolation-level

I'm learning Spring JPA and Hibernate. So I faced a problem.

I have this method

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
public void sendMoney(Long from, Long to, Double amount) {
    WalletEntity fromWallet = walletServiceImpl.getWallet(from);
    WalletEntity toWallet = walletServiceImpl.getWallet(to);
    fromWallet.setAmount(fromWallet.getAmount() - amount);
    toWallet.setAmount(toWallet.getAmount() + amount);

    TransactionEntity transaction = new TransactionEntity();
    transaction.setAmount(amount);
    transaction.setToWallet(toWallet);
    transaction.setFromWallet(fromWallet);

    transactionRepository.saveAndFlush(transaction);
}
```

I wanted to test it and created this:

```
@GetMapping("/send")
public void sendMoney() {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            accountServiceImpl.sendMoney(1L, 2L, 10D);
        });
    }
}
```

So when I read wallet, I get the old value but I made `Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ`. The values in database are wrong of course.
Can you explain what's wrong? Thank you!

Comment: What does it mean that the database values are wrong?

Comment: I'm executing 100 times take 10 "money" from wallet 1 to wallet 2. I'm expecting that value of wallet 1 is 1000 less and a value of the wallet 2 is 1000 more. But it's around 200-300 more less.

Comment: use 'Isolation.READ_COMMITTED' instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The isolation level REPTEABLE_READ works as intended.

You can get a good explanation here:

[Spring @Transactional - isolation, propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490852/spring-transactional-isolation-propagation)

But in order to clarify, this is what is happens:

```
                      Tx1      Tx2
                       |        |
Tx1 Read Wallet 1     100       |
Tx2 Read Wallet 1      |       100
Tx1 Discounts 10     100-10     |
Tx2 Discounts 10       |      100-10
Tx1 Commits            |        |
Tx2 Commits            |        |
Tx1 Read Wallet 1      90       |
Tx2 Read Wallet 2      |        90
```

So in order to control this behavior you have two options:

1. Use serializable transaction level that block the operation in order to process one by one (this has performance penalty)
2. Implement optimistic locking (the second transaction will throw an exception if it try to modify the same account at same time)

You can start reviewing optimistic locking here: [Optimistic locking in JPA how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069045/optimistic-locking-in-jpa-how-does-it-work)

Comment: I've tried to use serializable level, but it failed with deadlock

`Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747906/getting-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-transaction. But I believe you must deal with optimistic locking (you must avoid two modification to an wallet at same time).