How to execute code when user leaves the page, when their session ends, or if they close their browser
I have an older technology project that uses PrimeFaces 3.5 and Java EE. I am trying to implement a locking mechanism to prevent multiple users from editing the same entity simultaneously.
For example, when a user enters the edit page for a specific entity, I want to ensure that no other user can access the same entity for editing.
I have implemented the locking mechanism in the init() method of the page. However, I am unsure how to unlock the entity when a user leaves the page, when their session ends, or if they close their browser.
Any suggestions or best practices for managing this scenario?
Thank you.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069045/optimistic-locking-in-jpa-how-does-it-work

thanks for your comment but I think is not cover my requirement on release lock when users navigate or close browser

Just use @PreDestroy of view or session scoped bean. See abovelinked duplicates. Do note that JPA optimistic locking as suggested by Jasper is indeed a way much more efficient and robust approach. No need to waste time waiting for others who came in earlier but in the end do nothing. You just need to convince the product owner to change the requirement.
